# Angular js watch for value in two fucntions

Tags: angularjs

I want to update my data based on data received from back-end

there are two functions:

```
function getData(data){
Service.getRequest(url).then(function (_response) {
                console.log(_response)
                var res = _response
                if(res.data.success) {
                    $scope.$watch('data.photo', function() {
                        alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
                    });
                    data.photo = res.data.result;// this will tell that Image received against the corresponding data
                }
                else {
                    ctrl.errorCallBack =  true
                    ctrl.errorFunction =  5
                }
                $rootScope.showPreloader = false;
            });

}
```

now I have second function that receives  the selected data and called when clicked on button , now question is can I update the data inside this function when above Get request is completed:

```
function syncData(data) {
   console.log('image received')
   console.log(data)

}
```

First function is called n times based on number of images , now user click on second function to view Image but user don't see any Image because Image is not received yet but I want a way to update second function as Image is received

examples
ist image is loaded....user doesn't click on second function

2nd image is pending....user clicks on second function or second function is active

2nd image is received....active function image received

https://plnkr.co/edit/zKeDT84W6eF9cc3FpcmG?p=preview

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker (or similar) with a minimal example to show your issue?

Comment: okay i am working on it

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen https://plnkr.co/edit/zKeDT84W6eF9cc3FpcmG?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

If you use $scope for variables they will be automatically sync with DOM whenever it changes.

I did some changes for you in plnkr i hope solve your problem.

> http:// plnkr.co/edit/Ug53a03kB7Ap1EWf2jZK?p=preview